# Extract substring between two specified substrings using re.search(pattern, text) in Python

Tags: python, regex, list, python-2.7, substring

I have a string like, `"ENST00000260682_3_4_5_6_7_8_9_BS_673.6"`. I have to use regex in `re.search()` to extract a substring and write this into a list like this, `[3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]`, in Python.

I tried,

```
text="ENST00000260682_3_4_5_6_7_8_9_BS_673.6"
pattern=re.compile(r"^[[A-Z0-9]*_[.*]_BS]")
a=re.search(pattern, text)
print(a.group())
```

It returns, `'none'` and also `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'`.

Please help me with this.

Comment: Can you explain the nested brackets in your regular expression?

Comment: I am trying to first match all alphabets in capital letters or digits before the start of "_" and match everything after that, before "_BS". I am new to regex, so I am not sure what I've done is correct or not.

Comment: Brackets are used to specify a set of characters that are valid; you are trying to use them for much more than that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Search for all digits after  underscore before `_BS`:

```
import re
text="ENST00000260682_3_4_5_6_7_8_9_BS_673.6"
pattern=re.compile(r"_(\d+)")
a=re.findall(pattern, text[:text.find('_BS')])
print(a)
```

Output: `['3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9']`

Or, cast them to int if required:

```
a=[int(x) for x in re.findall(pattern, text[:text.find('_BS')])]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can easily achieve this using generators instead of regex:

```
def num_gen(s, delimiter='_', start_index=1, stop_token='BS'):
    # delimiter: the char you want to split your text for
    # start_index: where your want to start retrieving values
    # stop_token: stop retrieving when the token is encountered

    for x in s.split(delimiter)[start_index:]:
        if x != stop_token:
            yield x
        else:
            return
```

Usage:

```
t = "ENST00000260682_3_4_5_6_7_8_9_BS_673.6"
list(num_gen(t))

# ['3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9']
```

If possible I'd suggest avoiding use of regex unless necessary, *especially* if you are not familiar with it.  Here's a [relevant quote](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/223634/what-is-meant-by-now-you-have-two-problems):

> *Some people, when confronted with a problem, think
>   “I know, I'll use regular expressions.”
>
>   Now they have two problems.*

There are time and space for when regex is useful.  But until then, don't needlessly add it as part of your problem.